# Activities with singleTask launch mode and their position in the back stack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, back-stack, launchmode

In the official online Android [guide on tasks and back stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html), there's a piece of information i find self-contradicting. So i'd be grateful if somebody could help me figure it out.

First off, there's the following statement:

> Activities in the stack are never rearranged, only pushed and popped from the stack—pushed onto the stack when started by the current activity and popped off when the user leaves it using the Back button.

And then the *singleTask* launch mode is described, there's the following statement:

> The system creates a new task and instantiates the activity at the root of the new task. However, if an instance of the activity already exists in a separate task, the system routes the intent to the existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance.

Well, if i understand this correctly, the *singleTask* activities can only be the roots of their tasks, since they are created that way and the activities never trade places in the back stack. But how would such an activity react on receiving that call to its *onNewIntent()* method?

There's another remark about this matter on that page:

> As another example, the Android Browser application declares that the web browser activity should always open in its own task—by specifying the singleTask launch mode in the  element. This means that if your application issues an intent to open the Android Browser, its activity is not placed in the same task as your application. Instead, either a new task starts for the Browser or, if the Browser already has a task running in the background, that task is brought forward to handle the new intent.

So, the guide states that invoking a *singleTask* activity somehow brings it forward. But how can it be true if that activity is not on top of its task? Is the activity resumed, or it simply receives a call to its *onNewIntent()* method without being displayed to the user? I really don't understand.

PS: An almost identical [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886953/activity-marked-as-singletask-brought-forward) had already been asked more than a year ago, but there was no proper answer given to it. So while technically my question is a duplicate, i feel an urge to re-ask it since it really deserves a clear and unambiguous answer.

Answer (score 4):

I will try to answer your question(s).

Firstly,

> Activities in the stack are never rearranged, only pushed and popped
> from the stack—pushed onto the stack when started by the current
> activity and popped off when the user leaves it using the Back button.

This is actually wrong. Normally, activties in the stack are never rearranged, but you can bring an existing `Activity` to the front from somwehere else in the stack using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`. For example, your activity stack looks like this: A->B->C->D where `A` is the root activity (at the bottom of the stack) and `D` is the topmost activity that is in the foreground (being shown). If `D` now does this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will move the existing instance of activity `B` to the front of the task so that it will be shown on screen. The activity stack will now look like this: A->C->D->B.

Next you asked this:

> The system creates a new task and instantiates the activity at the
> root of the new task. However, if an instance of the activity already
> exists in a separate task, the system routes the intent to the
> existing instance through a call to its `onNewIntent()` method, rather
> than creating a new instance.

*Well, if i understand this correctly, the `singleTask` activities can only be the roots of their tasks, since they are created that way and the activities never trade places in the back stack. But how would such an activity react on receiving that call to its `onNewIntent()` method?*

In general, a `singleTask` activity is the root of its task. If there is already an existing task with a `singleTask` activity active in it, and you launch such an activity using `startActivity()`, then that task will be brought forward (so that it shows on screen) and `onNewIntent()` will be called on the existing instance of that activity. **However**, if the `singleTask` activity has started other activities in its task, all of those other activities will be finished (ie: the task is stripped back to its root `Activity`) BEFORE `onNewIntent()` is called on the existing instance of the `singleTask` activity.

There are cases where a `singleTask` activity is not the root of its task and then all bets are off (ie: the behaviour is not as documented). This can happen if the `singleTask` activity has the same `taskAffinity` as other activities in the app that are already active in a task. In that case, Android ignores the `singleTask` launch mode and treats the activity as if it has `standard` launch mode instead.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing the information. I need more clarifications, From the documentation our understanding is (Document link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable#AndroidManifestActivity_launchMode):
#1 LaunchMode is singleTask needs to add by system for FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT flag.
#2 LaunchMode is singleTop no need to add for FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT flag.

Comment: I need for some clarity, this is bug/issue in  AOSP 6/7/8/9/10.
#1 In AOSP 7, 8, 9 and 10 have similar implementation of adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT flag when launchMode is SingleTop.
#2 However, in the same AOSP 7, 8, 9 and 10 the FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT flag was not added when launchMode is SingleTask.
#3 in case of AOSP 7.1.2 the FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT flag was added when launchMode is SingleTask and not added in SingleTop..
#4 In case of AOSP 6 adds FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT flag both launchMode is SingleTop and SingleTask.

Comment: In our case, working fine for #3 and #4.
Please clarify which implementation is correct flow according to the concept of launchMode is singleTask and singleTop. @David

Comment: @SakthivelAppavu Interesting question. Unfortunately I cannot give you a definitive answer.  I'm not involved in AOSP development. I'm not sure why this flag is even relevant. I can't see a situation in which it would matter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please refer me, If there is any reference person contact. There is no major document available for changes in each API. Please guide me if there is any reference.

Comment: This will move the existing instance of activity B to the front of the task so that it will not be shown on screen. The activity stack will now look like this: A->C->D->B.  From that your answer. I have one query. #1 From the document if activity B start, then Activity C, D is destroyed by system. But you told stack order is changed. Please let me know if which API version is this use case?. @DavidWasser

Comment: @SakthivelAppavu I think you are confused. If you use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` the existing instance of that `Activity` is rearranged from wherever it is in the stack to the front of the stack and shown to the user. What document (and where in that document) says that "Activity C and D are destroyed"?

Comment: @SakthivelAppavu all versions of Android have the same behaviour regarding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` (that I know of).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Please refer here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack. @David

Comment: @SakthivelAppavu Sorry, what **exactly** in the referenced document are you talking about? Please be very specific as this stuff is complex and complicated.

Comment: Note: "singleTask" and "singleInstancePerTask" remove all activities that are above the starting activity from the task. For example, suppose a task consists of root activity A with activities B and C. The task is A-B-C, with C on top. An intent arrives for an activity of type A. If A's launch mode is "singleTask" or "singleInstancePerTask", the existing instance of A receives the intent through onNewIntent(). B and C are finished, and the task is now A. - Please check the above content from that URL. @David

Comment: @SakthivelAppavu Yes, that documentation is correct as far as I know. But that all has **nothing to do with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`** in my answer. This all has to do with the behaviour of `singleTask` launch mode. So I'm still confused about what you are asking. Perhaps you should open a new question and post your exact issue/question. Perhaps the confusion is from the concept of "bringing a task forward", which is not the same as rearranging activities within a task.

Comment: Okay Mr.David @David

Comment: I saw the AOSP 10, framework source code. in ActivityStarter.java class the method of startActivityUnchecked() implementation is missing the following code " mStartActivity.intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);" when the launchMode is SingleTask. Why is it not set in AOSP10 singleTask? @DavidWasser

Comment: @SakthivelAppavu That is a good question. I do not know. Sorry.